# Where audit logs of starting/stopping pods/containers are stored on k8s

Tags: logging, kubernetes, kubelet

On k8s, where audit logs of starting/stopping pods or containers are stored?

On k8s, we often store logs in hostpath /var/log, and let one agent mount this path and be charged of flush these logfiles. I wonder if there is one file in hostpath, store the audit logs of starting/stopping pods or containers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not enabled by default, but you can do it by [Audit](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/audit/), which is a part of `kube-apiserver` functionality.

You should create a policy for Audit which will describe what you want to catch and then you have 2 options how to store them - push somewhere using WebHook or write to files on a Master node.

To enable writing to a file, you should set a CLI flag for `kube-apiserver`: `--audit-log-path` with a path for log files.

Also, I highly recommend you to set a size limit for that files by `--audit-log-maxsize` because they can be really big.